# Extract fields from pubsub/stackdriver message

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-pubsub, google-cloud-stackdriver

I am exporting a custom metric from StackDriver to PubSub, which in turn will trigger a function. I need to extract tableId and datasetId fields, which in turn will be used to delete bigquery tables that are not compliant with enterprise standards.

Thus far, I have tried changing the name of the "data" field to protoPayload, textPayload, and I have received multiple errors. Some of the errors are "invalid key", "use bytes instead of dict", and mainly, "variable not defined."

```
import base64

def hello_pubsub(event, context):
    pubsub_message = base64.b64decode(event['protoPayload']).decode('utf-8')
    print(pubsub_message)
```

I would like to be able to extract individual fields (tableId, and datasetId) and use those in a BQ client to delete the offending table.

Update: Copied comment to question:

```
line 383, in run_background_function
_function_handler.invoke_user_function(event_object) 
File "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/functions/worker.py", line 217, in invoke_user_function return call_user_function(request_or_event) 
File "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/functions/worker.py", line 214, in call_user_function event_context.Context(**request_or_event.context)) 
File "/user_code/main.py", line 9, in hello_pubsub pubsub_message = base64.b64decode(event['protoPayload']).decode('utf-8') KeyError: 'protoPayload'
```

Comment: Can you maybe post the message that you are getting via pubsub?

Comment: line 383, in run_background_function _function_handler.invoke_user_function(event_object) File "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/functions/worker.py", line 217, in invoke_user_function return call_user_function(request_or_event) File "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/functions/worker.py", line 214, in call_user_function event_context.Context(**request_or_event.context)) File "/user_code/main.py", line 9, in hello_pubsub pubsub_message = base64.b64decode(event['protoPayload']).decode('utf-8') KeyError: 'protoPayload'

Comment: Thanks for replying! I had to shrink this a bit to meet the character limit.

Comment: Next time, edit your question and post as `code`.

Comment: @Jman ... sorry ... I wasn't clear.  You are receiving a message (data) via pub/sub and are trying to decode it.  Would it be possible to post a sample of this message/data?  If large, maybe post it to somewhere on the Internet and add a link.

Answer (score 1):

Use this framework as your starting point:

```
def hello_pubsub(event, context):
    if 'data' in event:
        pubsub_message = base64.b64decode(event['data']).decode('utf-8')
        print(pubsub_message)

        // Your custom data

        tableId = pubsub_message['requestMetadata']['serviceData']['tableInsertRequest']['resource']['tableName']['tableId']

        datasetId = pubsub_message['requestMetadata']['serviceData']['tableInsertRequest']['resource']['tableName']['datasetId']
```

Decode JSON from comments from below (the bottom is missing):

```
MY-MESSAGE: {
    "insertId":"-cr1b1ae1x199",
    "logName":" logs/cloudaudit.googleapis.com%2Factivity",
    "protoPayload":{
        "@type":"type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.audit.AuditLog",
        "authenticationInfo":{
        "principalEmail":"xxx"
    },
    "authorizationInfo":[{
        "granted":true,
        "permission":"bigquery.tables.create",
        "resource":"xxx"
    }],
    "methodName":"tableservice.insert",
    "requestMetadata":{
        "callerIp":"x",
        "callerSuppliedUserAgent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/x Safari/537.36,gzip(gfe)"},
        "resourceName":"x",
        serviceData"":{
            "@type":"type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.bigquery.logging.v1.AuditData",
            "tableInsertRequest":{
                "resource":{
                    "info":{},
                    "schemaJson":"{\n}",
                    "tableName":{
                        "datasetId":"citi_dev_gcp",
                        "projectId":"x",
                        "tableId":"outputCheck"
                    },
                    "view":{}
                }
            },
            "tableInsertResponse":{
                "resource":{
                    "createTime":"2019-06-20T18:42:21.106Z",
                    "expireTime":"2019-07-20T18:42:21.106Z",
                    "info":{},
                    "schemaJson":"{\n}",
                    "tableName":{
                        "datasetId":"name",
                        "projectId":"x",
                        "tableId":"outputCheck"
                    },
                    "updateTime":"2019-06-20T18:42:21.151Z",
                    "view":{}
                }
            }
        },
        "serviceName":"bigquery.googleapis.com","status":{}
    },
    "receiveTimestamp":
```

Comment: Thanks, John. When using this code, I receive the following:

Comment: packages/google/cloud/functions/worker.py", line 383, in run_background_function _function_handler.invoke_user_function(event_object) File "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/functions/worker.py", line 217, in invoke_user_function return call_user_function(request_or_event) File "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/functions/worker.py", line 214, in call_user_function event_context.Context(**request_or_event.context)) File "/user_code/main.py", line 6, in hello_pubsub mydata = pubsub_message['message']['data'] TypeError: string indices must be integers

Comment: What does this line print `print(pubsub_message)`

Comment: The output of this does indeed print the full Stackdriver log, between brackets, with the name of the function preceding: table-delete-test 123456880987 {“insertId”: “-98765432123ml”, “logname”: “projects/tf-my-simple-test”, “protoPayload”:{“@type”: “type.googleapis.com”}  much more here, but essentially a massive dictionary.

Comment: Look before this for the output from the print statement. Change this line `print(pubsub_message)` to `print('MY-MESSAGE:', pubsub_message)` to make it easier to see in Stackdriver.

Comment: MY-MESSAGE: {"insertId":"-cr1b1ae1x199","logName":" logs/cloudaudit.googleapis.com%2Factivity","protoPayload":{"@type":"type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.audit.AuditLog","authenticationInfo":{"principalEmail":"xxx"},"authorizationInfo":[{"granted":true,"permission":"bigquery.tables.create","resource":"xxx"}],"methodName":"tableservice.insert","requestMetadata":{"callerIp":"x","callerSuppliedUserAgent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/x Safari/537.36,gzip(gfe)"},"resourceName":"x","serviceData"

Comment: ":{"@type":"type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.bigquery.logging.v1.AuditData","tableInsertRequest":{"resource":{"info":{},"schemaJson":"{\n}","tableName":{"datasetId":"citi_dev_gcp","projectId":"x","tableId":"outputCheck"},"view":{}}},"tableInsertResponse":{"resource":{"createTime":"2019-06-20T18:42:21.106Z","expireTime":"2019-07-20T18:42:21.106Z","info":{},"schemaJson":"{\n}","tableName":{"datasetId":"name","projectId":"x","tableId":"outputCheck"},"updateTime":"2019-06-20T18:42:21.151Z","view":{}}}},"serviceName":"bigquery.googleapis.com","status":{}},"receiveTimestamp":

Comment: Thanks for your continued help. I had to breakup the output into two posts.

Comment: I have updated my answer with new code that will process the posted JSON

Comment: Thanks! This is definitely getting closer, but I am still getting this error: File "/user_code/main.py", line 11, in hello_pubsub tableId = pubsub_message['requestMetadata']['serviceData']['tableInsertRequest']['resource']['tableName']['tableId'] TypeError: string indices must be integers "  Do I need to change the brackets?

Comment: That error means that the JSON you posted in your comment does not match the code that I wrote. I need the EXACT JSON, edit your question and post the exact output from the print statement (write the output to a file) and do not copy from Stackdriver.

Comment: Once you have the JSON, edit your question and include the JSON using the code block command: {}

Comment: OK, I will output to a file and repost. Thanks!